# Radar to Camera calibration and Projection

Tags: opencv, sensors, camera-calibration, calibration, ransac

I would like to know how to project x,y coordinates of the radar onto the 2d image of the camera. Presently i am using usb camera, AWR1642 TI mmwave radar and i did camera calibration. I have tried two methods to do the radar to camera calibration. First one is CV2.SolvePNP and second method is homography. Unfortunately, the both experiment results were not accurate. Its RMSE values are higher even after collecting more than 30 corresponding points. I have tried to reduce RMSE value, but its not working. can anyone suggest any solution to implement the radar to camera calibration ?

Comment: SolvePnP is used to compute a camera matrix(orientation+position) given 2D pixel points and corresponding 3D points. An homography is a projective transformation that can be used in various ways, but its very different from solvePnP. In general, an homography cannot map an arbitrary image to another arbitrary image... You should also consider using RANSAC.